# How to properly write the lag function?

Tags: sql, window-functions, lag

i have the following table :
[image]

And what i want to do is to calculate the difference in terms of days between the dates.
The first step that i'm trying to implement is to pull the previous rows and then calculate the difference.

Here's what i tried :

```
SELECT YEAR,MONTH,DAY,
       lag(DATE) OVER w AS Lag
FROM DATASET
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY YEAR , MONTH , DAY ORDER BY YEAR , MONTH)
```

when i try to implement the lag i get this error:

***check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lag***

Any help would be greatly appreciated , thank you

Answer (score 0):

To use `LAG()` you need to specify at least an ordering criteria for the rows, as in `lag(date) over(order by date)`.

For example:

```
select date - lag(date) over(order by date) as diff from dataset
```

This will compute a previous row by sorting the set by `date`.

You can also add subgroups by including `PARTITION BY` in the `OVER` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CTE` (or a subquery) to put your `LAG` function in, then perform a `DATEDIFF` function to get the day difference between two dates.

**CTE Version:**

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT YEAR, MONTH, DAY, DATE,
                LAG(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS Lag_Date
              FROM DATASET)
SELECT *, 
  COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DATE, Lag_Date), 0) AS Day_Diff
FROM CTE
```

**Subquery Version:**

```
SELECT *, 
  COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DATE, Lag_Date), 0) AS Day_Diff
FROM (SELECT YEAR, MONTH, DAY, DATE,
        LAG(DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS Lag_Date
      FROM DATASET) a
```

**Result:**

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | DATE | Lag_Date | Day_Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 01 | 30 | 2021-01-30 | null | 0 |
| 2021 | 02 | 27 | 2021-02-27 | 2021-01-30 | 28 |
| 2021 | 12 | 31 | 2021-12-31 | 2021-02-27 | 307 |
| 2022 | 01 | 29 | 2022-01-29 | 2021-12-31 | 29 |

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/p5KbyUkr).**